# Chaos-monkey to test DB retry in springboot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, java-8, spring-boot-chaos-monkey

in my microservice I am trying to introduce retry at the time of saving record into the `database`. that is actually working. but I need to test it in lower env without bringing our DB down. for that I googled and found `chaos monkey` is an option for the same. so I introduced the same in my code.

below is my service class.

```
public class DemoService {

    @Autowired
    private DemoRepo demoRepo;
    static private int i=0;

    @Retryable(value={SQLException.class},maxAttempts = 3, backoff = @Backoff(delay = 1000))
    public Demo save(Demo demo){
        log.info("Retry is working"+(i+1));
       return demoRepo.save(demo);
    }
}
```

`

and below is my `application.yml` file.

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chaostest
    username: root
    password: 1234
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
  profiles:
    active: chaos-monkey

chaos:
  monkey:
    enabled: true
    assaults:
      exceptionsActive: true
      exception:
        type: java.sql.SQLException
      level: 5
    watcher:
      demoRepo: true

logging:
  level:
    de:
      codecentric:
        spring:
          boot:
            chaos:
              monkey: DEBUG
```

The problem is chaos monkey is not creating any issue for database. my transaction is getting saved on first time only. I want to test if retry is working properly?

1. what changes I need to do on configuration or code so that chaos-monkey works properly
2. is there any other way to test the same without bringing DB down?